# CodeIgniter : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003]

Tags: codeigniter, exception, pdo

***Please help me understand :*** 
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on XXXXXXXXX.

Note : 
The Application is build on **CodeIgniter** Framework.
It is able to connect to DB sometimes, as it **allows to login** which is DB - authenticated.

Comment: did you change your database,or what version of mysql you are using currently

Comment: I did not update any database configurations.

Comment: i mean did you update your  DBMS?